# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../data/mnist.pkl.gz'

Tags: python, import, neural-network

I'm new to Python and self-teaching myself neural networks from this http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html and I'm having trouble importing the files that I've downloaded for the exercises. This is the error message I keep getting:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
        training_data, validation_data, test_data = mnist_loader.load_data_wrapper()
      File "mnist_loader.py", line 68, in load_data_wrapper
      File "mnist_loader.py", line 42, in load_data
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 34, in open
        return GzipFile(filename, mode, compresslevel)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 94, in __init__
        fileobj = self.myfileobj = __builtin__.open(filename, mode or 'rb')
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../data/mnist.pkl.gz'
```

I've looked around and tried this:

```
>>> open('Users/bryanjordan/Documents/neural-networks-and-deep-learning-master/mnist.pkl')
```

but get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    open('Users/bryanjordan/Documents/neural-networks-and-deep-learning-master/mnist.pkl')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Users/bryanjordan/Documents/neural-networks-and-deep-learning-master/mnist.pkl'
```

Comment: Change path to `open('/Users/bryanjordan/Documents/neural-networks-and-deep-learning-master/mnist.pkl')` and check. ensure this is the correct full path.

Comment: you do not have that file or directory with that name in your system. did you check that file and pass?

Comment: Read about [current working directory](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_getcwd.htm)

Comment: I tried changing directories with os.getcwd() and re-downloaded then switched directories to that specific folder with 'os.chdir('/Users/bryanjordan/Downloads/neural-networks-and-deep-learning-master/')' but still having the same issue.

Comment: Reread [current working directory](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_getcwd.htm) - _"The method `getcwd()` **returns current working** directory of a process."_, **NOT** changing!

Answer (score 0):

I also meet this question. And I find the solution to solve this problem.

If you run the code in the python console, please first use "cd" into the "/src" folder, and run the code.

If you run the code in a python file (like me), you should put the file into the "/src" folder.

It will be solved. The only reason is that the relative path. You should stand in the right place.

Hope to help you.